# Making background 100% width in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've pushed up a new page.

There's one issue. The top portion needs to have a full 100% width, but rails automatically wraps it in a container class which gives it a padding on either side.

To remove the padding, I'd have to remove the container class from the template thats wrapping the the learn_more erb file.

How might I do this? I'd like to make it so the fray background is 100% width, ultimately not showing any white on left and right sides.

This is the page that I'm referring to:

http://rocky-depths-3714.herokuapp.com/learn_more

Thanks.

**Update (Layout.html.erb)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= @page_title ? "#{@page_title} | #{ Saas::Config.app_name }" : Saas::Config.app_name %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Illustrative streaming movie clips" %>">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/landing_slider' if action_name == 'home' && !user_signed_in? %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jcarousel.js' %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the first and second carousel by class selector.
    // Note that they use both the same configuration options (none in this case).
    jQuery('.first-and-second-carousel').jcarousel();

    // If you want to use a caoursel with different configuration options,
    // you have to initialise it seperately.
    // We do it by an   id selector here.
    jQuery('#third-carousel').jcarousel({
      vertical: true
    });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
        animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-4', classout : 'dl-animate-out-4' }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your layout file? i think you have used container class in layout file and it's wrapping up learn_more template

Comment: What's wrong with just using `width: 100%` on the top-container div?

Comment: Cheers, It already is at 100%, you can try using Inspect Element to debug. There were a couple ideas but they didn't work when scaling the window down/ weren't mobile friendly.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

If what you're referring to is an image, you could use [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) CSS property to get it working

> [`background-size: cover;`](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

or

```
background-size: 100%;
```

--

**HTML**

Your background is not an image, it's a block colour.

This means your CSS is not the problem - it's the structure of **your** HTML elements (specifically, that your top container is wrapped by another `div`, preventing it from ever attaining 100% width).

Rails will not wrap an element in a `container` - it only takes your HTML & outputs them on the page. The difference is if you use the system. Looking at your `layout`, it seems this is defined in `#app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb`

Inside this document, you'll have this somewhere:

```
<div class="container">
 ...
</div>
```

You need to remove the `container` div, or at least change it to be 100% width.

--

**max-width**

I also found something else:

[image]

This basically means you'll never be able to have your `container` div with any width higher than `750px` - if you make it `100%`, you'll need to ensure it's able to fit in correctly.